# Processing a Outlook calendars own formula items

Tags: c#, outlook, formulas

I have to process Outlook calendar items in a C# application. My Problem: I have a self constructed Formula for Outlook Appointments and I whant to access to the data of this own Formula Region (created in the developer tab/Formulas).

Here my code without using the own fields:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace mapiNamespace = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder CalendarFolder = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items outlookCalendarItems = null;

oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application[];
mapiNamespace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");

CalendarFolder = mapiNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
outlookCalendarItems = CalendarFolder.Items;
outlookCalendarItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;

oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application[];
mapiNamespace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");

foreach (Folder fold in mapiNamespace.Folders) {
  if (folder.DefaultItemType == OlItemType.olAppointmentItem) {

    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem item in folder.Items) {
        //Do stuff with the item (Subject, Location, Start, End, Categories)
        //Also whant to access to item fields defined in own Formular here
    }
  }
}
```

The code works fine, but I don't know how to access the data of my selfconstructed formula fields.
Any ideas or different solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the property containing the Information:

```
            For Each p As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemProperty In item.ItemProperties
                Try
                    MsgBox(p.Name & "    " & p.Value.ToString())
                    'One of thousends of attributes
                Catch e As System.Exception
                End Try
            Next
```